# In this diagram, which resistors are parallel and which are in series?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

In this image, which resistors are in parallel and which are in series? Is there a general rule for this, or is it just intuitive? I can't seem to figure it out.

[image]

Comment: The general method is to use [Kirchhoff's circuit laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws) – this gives you a linear system of equations for all the currents and voltages in the network (you have to close your circuit and add a voltage source, and then apply the method as shown in the example).

Answer (score 2):

A [bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_circuit). The simplest circuit you cannot reduce to series and parallel subcircuits. Not too surprising that you can't figure it out.

Comment: So if I'm trying to solve for an unknown resistance in a circuit that has this, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: See the link in my answer.

Comment: @BillAlexopoulos you can solve it the hard way with simultaneous equations, or you can use the formulas on Wikipedia.